# Can't call method "request" on an undefined value at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 563

Tags: perl, web

In my perl script I want to stop the redirection page by setting $mech->redirect_ok(0);
But I am getting the following error:-
Can't call method "request" on an undefined value at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 563

The perl program is as follows for your reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use utility;
use WWW::Mechanize;

$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );

my $num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 2) {
  print "\nUsage: ./my_script.pl username password\n\n";
  exit;
}

my $username = $ARGV[0];
my $password = $ARGV[1];

$username = main::trim ($username);
$password = main::trim ($password);

$mech->credentials( $username => $password );
$mech->redirect_ok(0);
$mech->get( '<home page of the web address>.jspa' );
print $mech->content();
```

Please suggest....

Answer (score 2):

`redirect_ok` is a callback function called internally by LWP to discover whether a particular redirection is admissable. It is used by subclassing `LWP` and overloading `redirect_ok` to perform more complex tests on the request and response.

The method takes two parameters, an `HTTP::Request` and an `HTTP::Response`. You are passing zero as the `HTTP::Request` and `undef` as the `HTTP::Response`. Zero is useless as a parameter to the user agent `request` method, so the program crashes.

I'm unclear exactly what need, but to disable all redirects you should use the `requests_redirectable` method, which takes a list of HTTP request types that are valid for redirection. By default it is set up as

```
$mech->requests_redirectable([qw/ GET HEAD /]);
```

so just a POST redirection will be denied. To prevent redirections of all request types, pass an empty list like this

```
$mech->requests_redirectable([]);
```

Comment: Thanks Borodin. I tried with $mech->requests_redirectable([]); to deny redirection. Now I am not getting anything in content from the url. I tried debugging it, but still wont get any idea why? Can you please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.